# How do I pass button action from a nested collectionView cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a MainCollectionView used for scrolling between items, inside of one of these cells I have another collectionView with cells. In that collection view, I have a button for each cell. My question is how do I pass action from my button to my MainCollectionView when it is tapped? I did create protocol for that button in the cell but I don't know how to let MainCollectionView know when my button is tapped. I can call action from my cell class but I think it is better to run it in Model which is my MainCollectionView. Below is my button protocol.

```
protocol ThanhCaHotTracksCellDelegate: class {
func handleSeeAllPressed()}

weak var delegate: ThanhCaHotTracksCellDelegate?


@objc func handleSeeAllButton(){
 delegate?.handleSeeAllPressed()
}
```

Comment: you can use `UIButton`'s `addTarget(_ target: Any?, action: Selector, for controlEvents: UIControlEvents)` method to add target/action for particular event of that button

Answer (score 6):

LIke NSAdi said, you're on the right track, but the delegate pattern is a bit much overhead for just a single task like notifying about a button press.

I prefer using closures, because they're lightweight and helps to keep related code together.

### Using Closures

This is what I'm always doing in `UITableView`. So this will work in `UICollectionView` too.

```
class MyTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    var myButtonTapAction: ((MyTableViewCell) -> Void)?

    @IBAction func myButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        myButtonTapAction?(self)
    }
}
```

So when I dequeue my cell and cast it to `MyTableViewCell` I can set a custom action like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCellReuseIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell

    cell.myButtonTapAction = { cell in
        // Put your button action here
        // With cell you have a strong reference to your cell, in case you need it
    }
}
```

### Using direct reference

When you're dequeueing your `UICollectionView` cell you can obtain a reference to your button by casting the cell to your cell's custom subclass.

Then just do the following

```
cell.button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapButton(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

And outside have a function:

```
@objc func didTapButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    // Handle button tap
}
```

Downside of this is that you have no direct access to your cell. You could use `button.superview?` but it's not a good idea since your view hierarchy could change...

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I can't use your suggestion because my MainCollectionView doesn't setup the cell that has the button. As I mentioned in my post, my sub collectionView takes care of that part. Anyway, right now, I just use protocol to pass action to my sub CollectionView and then from it, pass it to MainCollectionView.

Comment: Sorry I was too fast reading your question ^^. But you could also pass your closure multiple times like you do with your delegate...

Comment: @fl034 I have implemented the Closure solution so many times, now, even creating a new collection view with a button (actually a tvOS TVPosterView - still an UIControl) taking the whole cell, and the IBAction never ever gets called. The only way I am to catch a button pressed is via "collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)", after setting the delegate. What am I missing??

Comment: @MicheleDall'Agata you should post a new question, since this could be a whole different issue. Add a few more details about how you built your UI...

Comment: @fl034 I did, actually. Here the new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56912775/swift-ibaction-for-uicontrol-in-collection-view-cell-never-gets-called - Thanks for replying!

Comment: @fl034 never mind, I have finally solved it! After 4 days.. It's a matter with the tvOS focus, the cell was focused so the UIControl couldn't get the action. I fixed it describing the solution in my question.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track.

Make sure MainCollectionView (or the class that contains) it implements `ThanhCaHotTracksCellDelegate` protocol.

Then assign the `delegate` as `self`.

Something like...

```swift
class ViewController: ThanhCaHotTracksCellDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        subCollectionView.delegate = self
    }
}
```